# golang string.ToLower not working

Tags: go

I have a simple input string which I need to read and count the repeated words.

But, while doing that I need to convert the string to lower case, but some how the func ToLower is not working.

I have attached the golang link, Please, help me understand what can be the issue.

https://play.golang.org/p/OnQW-pgQxqq

Also pasting the code.

```
func main() {
    input := `
one
two Two
three Three Three;
four four four, four
five? five. five, five Five`
    countwords(input)
}

type kv struct {
    key string
    val int
}

type kvlist []kv

// need to define custome interface to make this work:
func (kv kvlist) Less(i, j int) bool { return kv[i].val < kv[j].val }
func (kv kvlist) Swap(i, j int)      { kv[i], kv[j] = kv[j], kv[i] }
func (kv kvlist) Len() int           { return len(kv) }

//sort the words by value
func sortmap(wordmap map[string]int) []kv {
    list := make(kvlist, len(wordmap))
    i := 0
    for k, v := range wordmap {
        list[i] = kv{k, v}
        i++
    }
    // we need to make few more modification to change this but,
    // for now lets assume it works.
    sort.Sort(sort.Reverse(list))
    return list
}

func countwords(str string) []kv {
    count := make(map[string]int)
    reg, err := regexp.Compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    lines := strings.Split(str, "\n")
    for _, line := range lines {
        line := reg.ReplaceAllString(line, "")
        strings.ToLower(string(line))
        repeatwords := strings.Fields(line) // count the repeated words
        fmt.Println(repeatwords)
        for _, word := range repeatwords {
            if _, ok := count[word]; ok {
                count[word]++
            } else {
                count[word] = 1
            }
        }
    }
    //once counted now sort the map based on values(repeated words).
    ret := sortmap(count)
    fmt.Println(count)
    return ret
}
```

Comment: strings.ToLower returns the lower case string.  The application ignores the return value.

Comment: You’re not using the result of ToLower

Comment: Sorry guys that was a dumb mistake.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your current code example is cluttered with 95% irrelevant details. Further, in many cases, and certainly in this one, doing so would show you the error before you even ask the question.

Comment: @Flimzy: I didnt get your comment. Looks like you did not read my question. Please, read it once again and please comment. Thanks.

Comment: I did read your question. It's full of mostly irrelevant code. If you were to create an MCVE, your question would be much more readable, plus in the process of creating a minimal example, you most likely would have solved your own problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, based on [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#ToLower), `strings.ToLower` expects an string and RETURNS an string, so basically you have to assign the result of `ToLower` to a variable, something like the following will do the trick

```
line = strings.ToLower(string(line))
```